# Why do images flip when the sample is raised in Fourier Domain OCT imaging?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, coherence

Why does raising the sample under a FD OCT machine cause the image to flip at the top? I know that FD OCT is looking at the time delays of backscattered light at every tissue layer which interferes with the reference beam. Then a fourier transform of this interference yields the frequencies which correspond to specific depths in the tissue.

So if I were to shift the sample up, they the positive frequencies should also shift to the left towards 0? But since there are also negative frequencies in the fourier transform, then the negative frequencies should also shift to the right towards 0. At some point the frequencies from the positive and negative sides switch and create a mirror image. I am trying to make sense of this phenomena and I am wondering if I have gotten the correct interpretation?